# Python "a=a-b" and "a-=b" are really equivalent?

Tags: python

It seems that `a = a-b` differs from `a -= b` and I don't know why.

Code:

```
cache = {}
def part(word):
    if word in cache:
        return cache[word]
    else:
        uniq = set(word)
        cache[word] = uniq
        return uniq

w1 = "dummy"
w2 = "funny"

# works
test = part(w1)
print(test)
test = test-part(w2)
print(test)
print(cache)

# dont't works
test = part(w1)
print(test)
test -= part(w2) # why it touches "cache"?
print(test)
print(cache)
```

Result:

```
set(['y', 'm', 'u', 'd'])
set(['m', 'd'])
{'dummy': set(['y', 'm', 'u', 'd']), 'funny': set(['y', 'n', 'u', 'f'])}
set(['y', 'm', 'u', 'd'])
set(['d', 'm'])
{'dummy': set(['d', 'm']), 'funny': set(['y', 'n', 'u', 'f'])}
```

As you can see, the third and the last line differs. Why in the second case the variable "cache" is different? `test -= part(w2)` is not like `test = test-part(w2)`?

**Edit 1** - Thanks for the answers, but why the var `cache` changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are different. Compare the following:

```
>>> x = set([1,2,3])
>>> y = x
>>> y -= set([1])
>>> x
set([2, 3])

>>> map(id, (x, y))
[18641904, 18641904]
```

with

```
>>> x = set([1,2,3])
>>> y = x
>>> y = y - set([1])
>>> x
set([1, 2, 3])

>>> map(id, (x, y))
[2774000, 21166000]
```

In other words, `y -= set(...)` changes `y` in place. Since both `x` and `y` refer to the same object, they both change.

On the other hand, `y = y - set(...)` creates a new object, rebinding `y` to refer to this new object. `x` is unaffected since it still points to the old object.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand why `cache` changes: in my code there's no `cache = test` or similar lines.

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli: You return references to objects that are stored in the cache. If the object is modified through such a reference, the contents of the cache changes.

Answer (score 6):

`a = a - b` is an operation which replaces `a` with a new object - the result of `a - b`.

`a -= b` is an operation which operates on `a` in-place and modifies it using `b`.

On some things, these two are equivalent, on others, they are not. The obvious case is on immutable objects, where they act the same. On mutable objects, as you have found, there is a large difference.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand why `cache` changes.

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli Because in Python, variables are names that reference objects. You stuck another name tag (`cache`) onto your object, so when you change it using the name `a`, won't magically not change under it's other name.